# Aggregate columns to rows using column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],'Q8_4_1':[1,2,3], 'Q8_5_1':[2,5,7],'Q8_4_2':[6,7,8], 'Q8_5_2':[9,10,11]})
```

[image]

The columns represent the same variable only for different files. As such, the structure is as follows Q8_4_(file1), Q8_4_(file2) and so on. I would like to transform the dataframe to have the following representation:

[image]

Currently I am running a less than optimal solution which involves hardcoding the column index and splitting the dataframe by file_id like so:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,:3]
df1.columns = ["ID","Q8_4","Q_5"]
df1["File_ID"] = 1

df2 = df.iloc[:,3:]
df2["ID"] = df["ID"]
df2.columns = ["ID","Q8_4","Q_5"]
df2["File_ID"] = 2

pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
```

Is there any pandas functionality that would help me achieve this at a scalable level?

Comment: use pivot option

Comment: Be careful. if you use df.columns to rename, the sequence would probably change. Try to use df.rename(columns=Dict). In this case, you actually concat Q8_5_2 with Q8_4_1. I think this is not what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Step 0: create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],'Q8_4_1':[1,2,3], 'Q8_5_1':[2,5,7],'Q8_4_2':[6,7,8], 'Q8_5_2':[9,10,11]}).set_index("ID")

# Step 1: create a function to split the column names
def split_col(s): 
    comp = s.split("_") 
    return "_".join(comp[:-1]), comp[-1] 

# Step 2: create a new index for the columns and update it
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(map(split_col, df.columns)))

# Step 3: stack based on level #1
df = df.stack(level=1)

# Step 4: nope, that's it
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you! Adding df = df.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={"level_1":"File_ID"},inplace=True) to your solution gave me the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `groupby` on `axis=1` and `concat`:

```
col=df.columns[1:].str.rsplit('_',1).str[0]
```

---

```
final=pd.concat([g.stack().droplevel(1) for _,g in 
               df.set_index('ID').groupby(col,axis=1)],axis=1,keys=col).reset_index()
final=final.assign(File_ID=final.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1)
print(final)
```

---

```
   ID  Q8_4  Q8_5  File_ID
0   1     1     2        1
1   1     6     9        2
2   2     2     5        1
3   2     7    10        2
4   3     3     7        1
5   3     8    11        2
```